# Nginx is down and I can't start it

Tags: nginx, debian

Nginx (1.4.1) has always worked for me - until now. For some reason I couldn't stop/restart the server, so I had to kill the process.

And now I can't start it. I don't get any response what so ever when running any nginx command, except from two of them; `service nginx status` gives me:

> [FAIL] nginx is not running ... failed!

And `service nginx testconfig` runs forever until I have to abort it.

I'm having panic over here - what should I do?

Comment: check /etc/inid.d/nginx

Comment: It's untouched. Or do you seek any particular?

Comment: have you updated or upgrade something before you restart?

Comment: Well, actually I made some changes in the configuration for Postfix. The changes are for `myorigin`, `myhostname` and setting `inet_interfaces = loopback-only`. Then I restarted Postfix successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should check the error_log of nginx，**
it will help you to find out what problem it is.
and set the error_log level to debug

Comment: Thanks god... Sometimes you simply forget to check the error logs. The problem was an invalid configuration for *another* site on the same server. For some reason Nginx didn't notice. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think is port problem . Check the

Comment: delete  openresty generate "nginx.pid"  .try again !

Comment: I also tried that. Sorry for not mentioning the troubleshooting process. :-)